# VerbTex cases problem

Tags: xetex, pdftex, cases, android, verbtex

I wrote this in VerbTex, and idk why it only puts the first case in curly brackets ( first time learning LaTeX, only two days since is started )

```
$|f(x)| = \begin{cases}
f(x), f(x)\leq 0 \\  
  -f(x), f(x)\geq 0 \\ 
 \end{cases}$
```

[image]

Comment: I thought the website will show the output of the code, terribly sorry

Comment: please post an example that demonstrates the problem, also what is verbtex ?  I have used tex for 30 years and I don't think I have heard of it.

Comment: `cases` needs `&` not `,` to separate the expressions from the conditions.

Comment: @David Carlisle, the problem is as shown in the picture also verbtex is an android LaTeX app

Comment: No we can not run that fragment and if I guess a surrounding document so I can run it then it does not produce the output shown.

Comment: Well, i tried to write & instead, but i always get " error misplaced alignment tab character & "

Comment: Oh perhaps you have not loaded amsmath. That is the problem with only posting fragments it is hard to debug if the error is in code not shown.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

[image]

You did not provide an example document but the output you show suggests that you did not load `amsmath` (so picked up a legacy plain tex version of `\cases` expecting a different syntax.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$|f(x)| = \begin{cases}
f(x), f(x)\leq 0 \\  
  -f(x), f(x)\geq 0 \\ 
 \end{cases}$

\bigskip

or with alignment:


$|f(x)| = \begin{cases}
f(x),& f(x)\leq 0 \\  
  -f(x),& f(x)\geq 0 \\ 
 \end{cases}$


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is just as you said. The app seems to use "utf8"

Comment: @somename_idk latex uses utf-8 by default, but that is not actually relevant here as the input just uses ascii characters.